# Image conversion from JPEG to Byte Array in Android

Tags: android

I want to convert JPEG image to Byte Array in android. I am using the below code:

```
if (PhotoScreen.st_bitPicture != null)
            {

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                boolean b = PhotoScreen.st_bitPicture.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                Log.w("test2", "BOOLEAN  BOOLEAN BOOLEAN BOOLEAN :"+b);
                m_base64EncodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            }
```

But it is compressing the image. How can i do without compressing the image?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "compressing", do you mean "convert it to base 64?". You already have a byte array, and then you encode it in base 64. What is your desired output?

```
PhotoScreen.st_bitPicture.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
```

Creates an in-memory JPEG image (JPEG compressed).

```
bos.toByteArray()
```

Creates a byte array with the JPEG data. That's what you want.

```
Base64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Encodes this data to base 64. Just omit that step if you don't want base 64. If you want any other output (like a string with the byte array converted to hexadecimal), then do that instead.

Comment: it is going to the server with different pixel size..suppose if i take it in 300*400 then it is storing in 200*225.

Comment: `Bitmap.compress` does not resize the image. That must have happened when you created your bitmap.